# SQLALCHEMY - couldn't get new record after insert with stored procedure

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I use SQLALCHEMY with ORM class as follow:

**Registration Class / Table:**

```
class Registration(db.Model):
    """ Activation Registrations Model for storing user Registrations related details """
    __tablename__ = "user_registrations"

    RegistrationID = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    RegistrationType = db.Column(db.Enum('Local', 'Facebook', 'Google'), nullable=False, server_default=text('Local'))
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.UserID'), nullable=False)
    Email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        # private
        self.__dao = DAO(db)

    def __init__(self, registration_type, user_id, email):
        # private
        self.__dao = DAO(db)

        # public
        self.RegistrationType = registration_type
        self.UserID = user_id
        self.Email = email

    def save(self):
        stored_proc = 'pUserRegister'
        parameter = [self.UserID, str(self.RegistrationType), str(self.Email)]
        result = self.__dao.call_procedure(stored_proc, parameter)
        return {'status': status, 'message': message, 'data': data}
```

**User class/Table:**

```
class User(db.Model):
    """ User Model for storing user related details """
    __tablename__ = "users"

    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    Email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    UserName = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)

    # relationships
    Registrations = db.relationship('Registration', backref='users', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, email, username):
        # private
        self.__dao = DAO(db)

        # public
        self.Email = email
        self.UserName = username

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        # private
        self.__dao = DAO(db)

    @staticmethod
    def register(registration_type, user_id, email):

        if user_id and user_id > 0:
            # check if user exists
            user = User.query.filter(User.UserID == user_id).first()
            if not user:
                return {'status': False, 'data': {'message': 'Invalid User'}}

        # initiate Registration
        reg = Registration(registration_type, user_id, email)
        result = reg.save()
        return result
```

**with DAO Class:**

```
class DAO(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        # Unpack Other Database Arguments Here
        self.__db = db

        engine = self.__db.engine
        self.connection = engine.raw_connection()

    def call_procedure(self, procedure, data=()):
        try:
            with self.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
                cursor.callproc(procedure, data)
                result = json.dumps(cursor.fetchall(), cls=DateTimeEncoder)
                result = json.loads(result)
                result = {"status": True, "data": result}
                return result
        except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
            log.info('>>>>> Exception: %s <<<<<', e)
            result = {'status': False, 'data': {'message': "ERROR: {}".format(e)}}
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            self.connection.commit()
            self.connection.close()

        return result
```

so i tried to execute my code as follow: (just for testing to get userID 70)

```
user = User.query.filter(User.UserID == 70).first()
log.info('>>>>> debug1: %s <<<<<', user)
```

with code above, I can get the user object propoerly
then I do below:

```
resp = User.register(registration_type='Facebook', user_id=None, email='asd@aaswrtr.com')
log.info('>>>>> debug2: %s <<<<<', resp['data']['UserID'])
```

with code above I can see that the stored proc is executed properly and I can get the newly inserted ID from `resp['data']['UserID']` and I can see data recorded in MYSQL DB

then I execute below to get the data that I just inserted using SP above:

```
user = User.query.filter(User.UserID == resp['data']['UserID']).first()
log.info('>>>>> debug3: %s <<<<<', user)
```

**Problem**: I received **user = None** in my last statement above.
what's possibly went wrong here?

Comment: In issuing your debug1 query you have started a transaction in `db.session` used by the query property `User.query`, before issuing your debug3 statement. MySQL's default transaction isolation level is repeatable read, so if a transaction is ongoing, it will not see newly committed data from other transactions, such as the one you use in your "DAO".

Comment: @IljaEverilä, Thanks for the comments, then how/what is the solutions to achieve my objective above? is there a way to get 'refreshed' record after SP execution from SQLALCHEMY?

Comment: You could either force a new transaction in `db.session` after using `User.register()` by rolling back before issuing new queries, namely your "debug3", or you could make it so that the `DAO` accesses the active connection of `db.session` and in effect runs its commands in the same transaction.

Comment: Thanks, so if i understand correctly here is: the issue is because my dao and db.session is using 2 diffrent connection thereby the new recorded data from db.session can't be retrieve with my dao session, am i right? Let me try later to see if this solving the issue.

Comment: Sorta, though I understood your code the other way around: `db.session`, which the query properties of model classes use, cannot retrieve the new data inserted by DAO, due to them using different connections and thus different transactions, because of [MySQL's default transaction isolation level of REPEATABLE READ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html).

Comment: Thanks, it actually work, I re-work my code to use the same DBModel object to callproc `DBModel.callproc()` (initially, my DBModel and db engine is completely separated)